# C# SCCM 2012 Administration Tool

Tags: c#, sccm

Im trying to program a simple administration tool for using with SCCM 2012. For our supporters, so they dont have to use Configuration Manager just for adding and removing applications from PCs.

I have made a little application so far, that list all the Add-On Collections in a ComboBox (e.g. adobe and so on) using query from SMS_Collection.

But i cannot figure out how i can add this collection to a computername/resource id?

Can anyone tell me a way? i studied SDK 2012 for SCCM but i still cant figure out how its done.

My code so far, but with a lot of commected out lines different things i tried.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ////connect to sccm
        this.sccmConnection.Connect("sccmserver");

        ////get a list of the avialable collections
        string collectionQuery = "SELECT * FROM SMS_Collection Where Name = '{0}'";
        WqlQueryResultsObject collections = this.sccmConnection.QueryProcessor.ExecuteQuery(collectionQuery) as WqlQueryResultsObject;
        foreach (WqlResultObject collection in collections)
        {
            this.cmbCollection.Items.Add(collection.PropertyList["Name"]);
        }
        if (this.cmbCollection.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.cmbCollection.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private WqlConnectionManager sccmConnection = new WqlConnectionManager();


    private void btnDeploy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (IResultObject oSystem in this.sccmConnection.QueryProcessor.ExecuteQuery("Select ResourceID From SMS_R_System Where NetBIOSName = 'PC1'"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(oSystem["ResourceID"].IntegerValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: In short you need to create either a query rule or a direct rule on the collection, and then use that add the computer's resource ID. See the below Microsoft articles on both of these methods:

[How to Create a Static Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj885572.aspx),

[How to Create a Dynamic Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj885690.aspx)

Comment: That means that i should create a dynamic Collection with one PC (e.g.) from the SMS_R_System Query? And using that temporary CollectionID to add to the CollectionID from the SMS_Collection? And if so how do i attach a Collection to another Collection?